# $.post() giving bad url string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I made a site that shows dynamically created HTML using ajax with jQuery.

On one part it shows diferent entries from a database table, and on each row there's a button to delete that specific entry from the database. This is the code that should make that happen:

```
$('body').on('click', '.deleteWaitlist', function(){
        console.log("Clicked on .deleteWaitlist name = " + $(this).attr('name'));

        // Get the varible name to send to your php
        var i = $(this).attr('name');
        console.log( "$(this).attr('name') = i" );

        $.post({
            url: "deleteWaitlist.php", 
            data: { id : i}, 
            success: function(result){
                console.log("Ajax success " + result);
            }, 
            //dataType: "html"
        });
        return false;
    });
```

However, when I click the button I get the error

```
POST localhost:8888/workplace/site/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but [object%20Object] is what we get from an undefined toSting() method right? I tried specifing diferent kinds of dataTypes but made no diference.

I can't seem to find the problem, can dataType be something besides xml, json, script or html? This function don't return anything so dataType is not even needed isn't it?

This is deleteWaitlist.php:

```
<?php
    include("con.php");    
    $sql = "DELETE FROM waitlist WHERE id=" . $_POST[id] . "";
    mysqli_query($c,$sql);
?>
```

EDIT: To clarify, the mentioned error shows only on the console, since I want an async site most buttons prevent navigation. On the actual page clicking the button has no effect. Also, this is the code that creates the buttons:

```
while ($places = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>". $places ['ID']."</td>";
    echo "<td>". $places ['NAME']."</td>";
    echo "<td>". $places ['CHAIRS']."</td>";
    echo "<td>". $places ['CREATED']."</td>";
    echo '<td>
        <button class="btn btn-default deleteWaitlist" type="submit" name="' . $places['ID'] . '">X</button>
        </td>';
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: What does the HTML of and around each button look like? That URL doesn't even match your `deleteWaitlist.php` URL in the AJAX call so I doubt it's directly related to the code you've shown so far

Comment: As a quick test, try `return false` in the click handler to prevent the event default and stop propagation. Put it just after your `$.post({...});`

Comment: Also, prepared statements are your friend. `$stmt = $c->prepare('DELETE FROM waitlist WHERE id = ?'); $stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST['id']); $stmt->execute();`

Comment: @Phil I don't know why the error gives an absolute path but my whole site is made with relative paths and it all works but this. I'll update the post with the HTML of the buttons

Comment: It's not that the error shows an absolute path (this is to be expected for networking errors), it's that it does not end with `deleteWaitlist.php`. I see nothing in the code provided that would result in `[object Object]`. Also, you haven't mentioned but do you see all the expected `console.log` entries?

Comment: `console.log( "$(this).attr('name') = i" );` should be `console.log( "$(this).attr('name') = " + i);` Is that outputting what you're expecting?

Comment: why not using `$.ajax({` instead `$.post({`

Comment: @Phil Oh ok, I missunderstood you. I see all console enties except the one on the success callback.

Comment: @Phil my request still pending, still waiting you to make your comment the answer :P

Comment: @TianRB If you taken my answer of your yesterday question, you won't be asking this question anyways, happy coding.

Comment: @shehary I was wrong. Didn't realise that `$.post(options)` is a jQuery 3.0 thing only

Comment: @Phil, not this one, i asked couple of days back about datetime convert inside array and insert into db, i will send you ping from that post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$.post expects the first param an URL string
If you want to pass an object with other options, you must use $.ajax.

Try

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "deleteWaitlist.php", 
            data: { id : i}, 
            success: function(result){
                console.log("Ajax success " + result);
            }
        });
```

> Correct me if I'm wrong, but [object%20Object] is what we get from an undefined toSting() method right?

You are right. When you use $.post with first parameter as object jQuery thinks it as post url and does toString() to that parameter.  In your case its like `object.toString()` which throws the error  `[object%20Object]`

Comment: Thanks, that worked! So can I use .post() if I serialize the input then? I'm kinda new to all this async hocus pocus

Comment: You can give inputs in the format jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )    Check the doc here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/   data param can be serialized or can be given as an object like {name: "John", age : 15}

Comment: @TianRB note that in jQuery 3.0+ you can use an *options* object in `$.post`